# Produce a variable amount of layouts programmatically within nested fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

So, as the title states, I wish to produce some amount of layouts within a Fragment which is in turn within a fragment. The number of layouts depends on the number of columns returned from a database, and the number of columns returned depends on which Fragment the user is currently on.

The first fragments are a BottomNavigation View, then the second set of Fragments are a range of swipe panels within each part of the BottomNavigation. It is in these fragments that I want to produce the variable number of layouts.

[Here is a screenshot of what I'm looking to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvC6D.png)

I was trying to create the Layouts within the OnCreateView() method for the inner Fragment but that is causing errors. I know that OnCreateView() returns a view so that must be wrong to try to create these layouts here.

I essentially have my main class which is divided into the 4 bottomNav fragments, each of which are divided into between 2-6 Fragments themselves.

Where should I be creating these layouts? Is there some other way to achieve the objective? Why is it not possible to create a layout within OnCreateView()? I'm very confused by the whole process, though the issue is probably a simple enough fix. Any help would be much appreciated.

If necessary I can provide code, though hopefully this is a simple enough issue that it is not needed.

---

EDIT: Below I have added the code I have so far:

MainActivity (which produces the BottomNavigation):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
private int mSelectedItem;
public static int numTabs;
public static String fragType;
public static String[] headings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            selectFragment(item);
            return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItem selectedItem;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
        selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
    } else {
        selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
    }
    selectFragment(selectedItem);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
    if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
        // select home item
        selectFragment(homeItem);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment frag = null;
    // init corresponding fragment
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //USER PROFILE
        case R.id.menu_home:
            numTabs = 3;
            fragType = getString(R.string.text_home);
            headings = new String[numTabs];
            headings[0] = "PROFILE HEADING 1";
            headings[1] = "PROFILE HEADING 2";
            headings[2] = "PROFILE HEADING 3";
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(fragType);
            break;
        //DISCOVER
        case R.id.menu_search:
            fragType = getString(R.string.text_search);
            numTabs = 6;
            headings = new String[numTabs];
            headings[0] = "DISCOVER HEADING 1";
            headings[1] = "DISCOVER HEADING 2";
            headings[2] = "DISCOVER HEADING 3";
            headings[3] = "DISCOVER HEADING 4";
            headings[4] = "DISCOVER HEADING 5";
            headings[5] = "DISCOVER HEADING 6";
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(fragType);
            break;
        //SCHEDULE
        case R.id.menu_notifications:
            fragType = getString(R.string.text_notifications);
            numTabs = 2;
            headings = new String[numTabs];
            headings[0] = "SCHEDULE HEADING 1";
            headings[1] = "SCHEDULE HEADING 2";
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(fragType);
            break;
        //FOLLOWED
        case R.id.menu_followed:
            fragType = getString(R.string.text_follow);
            numTabs = 3;
            headings = new String[numTabs];
            headings[0] = "FOLLOWED HEADING 1";
            headings[1] = "FOLLOWED HEADING 2";
            headings[2] = "FOLLOWED HEADING 3";
            frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(fragType);
    }

    // update selected item
    mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

    // uncheck the other items.
    for (int i = 0; i< mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
        menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId());
    }

    if (frag != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, frag, frag.getTag());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
}
```

Here's the MenuFragment class:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_TEXT = "arg_text";

private String mText;

private TextView mTextView;
private Button contactButton;
private Button logoutButton;

public static Fragment newInstance(String text) {
    Fragment frag = new MenuFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TEXT, text);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    ViewPager view = (ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    view.setAdapter(buildAdapter());
    return(result);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        mText = args.getString(ARG_TEXT);
    } else {
        mText = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_TEXT);
    }

    // initialize views
    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    contactButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.contactButton);
    logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logoutbutton);

    // set text
    mTextView.setText(mText);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(ARG_TEXT, mText);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new MidSectionAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
}
}
```

And here is the MidSectionAdapter:

```
public class MidSectionAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context ctxt=null;
String title;

public MidSectionAdapter(Context ctxt, FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
    this.ctxt=ctxt;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return(MainActivity.numTabs);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("MY PROFILE")) {
        return(ProfileFragment.newInstance(position));
    } else if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("DISCOVER")) {
        return(DiscoverFragment.newInstance(position));
    } else if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("SCHEDULE")) {
        return(ScheduleFragment.newInstance(position));
    } else {
        return(UpComingFragment.newInstance(position));
    }
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {

    if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("MY PROFILE")) {
        title = ProfileFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position);
    } else if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("DISCOVER")) {
        title = DiscoverFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position);
    } else if(MainActivity.fragType.equals("SCHEDULE")) {
        title = ScheduleFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position);
    } else {
        title = UpComingFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position);
    }
    return(title);
}
}
```

And here is an example of the inner Fragment (I have reverted it back to the code I had before I was having the issue, so it doesn't do much other than display "in panel x"):

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";
private TextView panelView;
private static String head;
private static int panelPosition;
String panelCheck;

static ScheduleFragment newInstance(int position) {
    ScheduleFragment frag=new ScheduleFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
}

static String getTitle(Context ctxt, int position) {
    head = MainActivity.headings[position];
    panelPosition = position;
    return(head);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_content, container, false);
    panelView = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.testFrag);
    int position=getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);
    if(getTitle(getActivity(), position).equals(MainActivity.headings[0])) {
        //MAY NOT NEED THIS NITIAL IF STATEMENT
        panelCheck = "in first panel";
    } else {
        //tableType = "Venue";
        panelCheck = "in second panel";
    }
    panelView.setText(panelCheck);

    return(result);
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are not using a RecyclerView for the inner views. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do your swipe panels have different layout each? If not then create just one layout xml file and create as many fragments using that single layout.

Comment: @theblitz How do you implement a RecyclerView, is it very different to Fragments? Perhaps I could show you my code and you could assist me? The innerViews will contain different content depending on BottomNav Fragment. Some will be images, others expandable texts, etc. Does that have an impact on the ability to use a RecyclerView? I am new to Android development, apologies for my ineptitude!

Comment: RecylerView is designed for displaying any number of views which are also scrollable if needed. They definitely do not have to be the same. They are many tutorials and examples of how to use it. You should work through one from start to finish.

Comment: @Yousefkhan Each swipe view within a BottomNav fragment (eg. the 3 panels corresponding to the "Profile" section) is the same layout, but then changing the BottomNav fragment will change the inner Fragment layout (eg. changing to "Discover" will mean the swipe fragments contain the same layout as each other, but different to those in "Profile")

Comment: @theblitz Thank you for the information! I'll try and get through a full tutorial immediately. Thank you for the swift response! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, you can create/add/replace n of fragments in Android Activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity)
        //or
        LinearLayout layout = getLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.your_activity);
        setContentView(layout)
}
```

Similarly you can create n of Views within Activity as well as Fragment.

```
    private LayoutInflater fragmentInflater,
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.fragmentInflater = inflater;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alto_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Basically you can create Views/ViewGroups add/remove views at any time you want. What you want is the **fragmentInflater** object.

According to your screenshot req, you may need a **ListView** or **RecyclerView** with different view types. If your list is small you can simply go head with **ScrollView + LinearLayout**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added my code for the project to my original post. Could you take a look and see how far wrong I've gone? I'm starting to think I may need to change a large chunk of the project. I'm unsure of where to implement what you are talking about due to the nature of the fragments being nested within my BottomNavigation View. I'm a complete novice at Android programming and middling at best when it comes to Java. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: In case you didn't see it in the comments below my original post:

 Each swipe view within a BottomNav fragment (eg. the 3 panels corresponding to the "Profile" section) is the same layout, but then changing the BottomNav fragment will change the inner Fragment layout (eg. changing to "Discover" will mean the swipe fragments contain the same layout as each other, but different to those in "Profile")

Comment: I saw your code. Basically you have to include a ListView in schedule_content.xml. Then initialize the same in onCreateView. Followed by that create a Cursor to get the respective DB result set and pass the same to your newly created ArrayAdapter. That's the one you're going to set for the above list. Now the view creation should happen in your custom Array Adapter getView method. You can also create different layouts in getView depends on your needs. Google how to create a listview with multiple custom rows/views. One more thing. You should pass a activity, or context or inflator to your cust

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look into what you suggested. Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using ListView over the other suggestion of RecyclerView?

Comment: RecyclerView is much better and richer than LisView. You have to include a Gradle path to your apps built.gradle to use this. Has a inbuilt view holder in its adapter model. The only huddle for a beginner is clickevent and cursor adapter. You need some extra helper classes for on item click and Cursor Adapter. On the other hand LisView is simple, powerful but legacy.

Comment: After messing around with the ListView I've managed to get it working, Thank you very much for all the help! You're a genius!!